# How to add an exe file as a resource in Java Maven Project?

Tags: java, maven

Background: I have an exe file that I want to copy from my Java Maven project into the user's home directory. After my project is done running, I will delete this exe file from their home directory. I need to use this exe file as a third party resource in order to execute what I need to do for this project

Issue: 
I have added the exe file both in my src/test/resources folder and also in my src/main/resources folder. When I just build the project with maven and run the test cases, the exe file is copied and deleted correctly.

However, when I run the Java project, the exe file fails to be ran. I get an error that says: This version of xxx.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.

The test folder and main folder references different resource folders which is why the test folder is successful while the main one is not.
I checked the target classes of my project. In the /target/test-classes folder, the .exe file remains untouched. It is 540 KB which is correct. In the /target/classes folder, the .exe file seems to have been modified. It is 786 KB. What is going on and how can I configure this so that the exe file does not get modified like how it is under the /target/test-classes during the build?

Comment: imo: not. first of all, if you want a Windows application, Java is not the language you should be using. The issue you seem to be having is the version of the OS. If you don't understand that using a 32 bit exe on a 64 bit os (or vice versa) might lead to trouble, you shouldn't be trying to write anything like it anyway

Comment: The executable is 32 bit to begin with. I have a 64 bit OS, and there is no issue. I am just wondering why the executable is being modified?

Comment: "This version of xxx.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running." -> this, you translate to: "there is no issue" ? ow..key.

Comment: That error message would not occur if the file is not modified. If I have the executable running on my machine, there is no issue, and when I run my test cases there is also no issue. There is only an issue when I run the Java project since it is referencing a different folder than the test-cases. My main question is: Why is the executable being modified, and how can I have it so that it does not get modified?

Comment: just "running a Java project" doesn't copy a file, unless you 've written code that actually copies it. have you tried looking into that?

Comment: Maybe my explanation is a bit unclear. What I mean is that I am copying the file from the resources of my project (target/classes folder). The file in that folder is modified. So this issue is happening even before I copy the file into the user home directory. I am confused about what is going on during the build

Comment: why on earth would you want to have an exe file in your build?

Comment: Well my main goal is to somehow get this exe file in the home directory and then delete it after the project is done running. I welcome any suggestions for a better implementation

Comment: Any chance you are using maven resource filtering to expand property names?

Comment: @WillShackleford, you helped me find a solution. I wasn't using any maven resource filtering nor was I specifying not to use any filtering. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html resolved my issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pom.xml

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>exe</nonFilteredFileExtension>
          </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html